# Why is a 301 redirect showing as 200 OK?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand why I can't seem to make this redirect work as a 301 redirect.

I coded a url shortening script earlier and this is the last step that I can't seem to understand..

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^shorten/(.*)$ shorten.php?longurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ redirect.php?url=$1 [L]
```

and this is my redirect.php page

```
include 'databaseClass.php';
$urlShortner = new urlShortner($db);

if(!preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_GET['url']))
{
    die('That is not a valid short url');
}

header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' .  $urlShortner->redirectUrl());
exit;
```

For some reason it's reporting as a 200 OK instead of a 301 perm redirect.. I've tried setting the rewriterule to [R=301] but the page stops working if I do.

Comment: It seems to work fine when I log the network requests in the inspector (Chrome). Perhaps you're just seeing the end result. What tool are you using to test?

Comment: I keep getting mixed results with various online tools, but with firefox http live headers I got 301, and I just tried chrome as well and it's a 301.. not sure why I keep getting mixed results with some tools, but it must be what you said.

Comment: in chrome make sure to check "preserve log" otherwise you will not have the chance to see the 301.